# update limit with sql

Tags: sql

Please can someone help me fix this query to add limitations. Here is the query below.

```
UPDATE
    table_1 A
    INNER JOIN table_2 B
SET
    A.column ='blabla'
WHERE
    A.column IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What dbms? (sql server, postgres, mysql, oracle...)

Comment: A `LIMIT` clause is meaningless without an `ORDER BY` expression, which itself doesn't mean much in an `UPDATE` statement. What is the *intent* of your code? I also note you have an `INNER JOIN` but you haven't specified the join criteria.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the complete query.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the complete query.     UPDATE
    table_1 A
    INNER JOIN table_2 B
SET
    A.column ='blabla'
WHERE
    A.column IS NULL AND B.column2 IS NULL
LIMIT 1

Comment: Two things: (1) Rather than posting your update with a comment, edit the question itself with any updates. (2) You still haven't specified join criteria. Join criteria looks like: inner join table_2 B *on B.id = A.id*.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only limits you can put on an update query are those specified in WHERE statement. If you want to update only one row, specify the row by unique key in the where statement, e.g A.id = 1;

Furthermore, as mentioned by Dai, you should specify join columns in A and B.